TScriptInterface<> nullptr automatically stops being null
I have a problem in my Unreal Engine 5 project with my TScriptInterface pointer.
Here is my IFBloc class :
class IFBloc {
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    IFBloc() {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Constructor: next object after init is %s"), next.GetObject() ? TEXT("valid") : TEXT("nullptr"));
    }
    TScriptInterface<UFBloc> next = nullptr;

        UFUNCTION(BlueprintNativeEvent, BlueprintCallable, Category="Bloc")
        void CleanChainedList();

        void CleanChainedList_Implementation()
         {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("chained list: next object is %s"), next.GetObject() ? TEXT("valid") : TEXT("nullptr"));
            UObject* Object = next.GetObject();
            if (Object != nullptr && next != nullptr) {
                UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Object not null"));
                // if (Object->GetClass()->ImplementsInterface(UFBloc::StaticClass()))
                // {
                //     // IFBloc::Execute_CleanChainedList(Object);
                // }
            }
            next.SetObject(nullptr);
        }
    
        // other functions
};

When I just do this with my Blueprint code (Action Shoot inherits from FBloc) :

Here is my log console :
Constructor: next object after init is nullptr
chained list: next object is valid
Object not null

I don't understand how it's possible that my 'next' variable change value and is not null after calling my function, even if I do nothing else to assign a value to this variable
When I try to do something with the new value assigned, like printing it, Unreal Engine crashes
Do you have any idea of how my variable gets a value without any reason, or of another check that I can do to be really sure that I never assigned a value to this variable ?

What does CleanChainedList() do?

@3CxEZiVlQ initially, the function was created to clean the chained list and remove recuresively every node from the chained list, but i've seen that when I call the function with "next" pointing to null, it behaves as if "next" is pointing on something

I did not ask about CleanChainedList_Implementation().

@3CxEZiVlQ if I understood it well, when I call "CleanChainedList" in blueprint, it automatically calls "CleanChainedList_Implementation"
Maybe the problem can come from there

The body of CleanChainedList is not shown. I guess it sets next.

@3CxEZiVlQ the body of CleanChainedList is like this in my code, I have nothing inside, I only use CleanChainedList_Implementation
